# Id is missing on second click on edit button

Tags: reactjs

Clicking on `this.editSiteType(index, data)` (line: 230), everything works as expected in the method. After editing is rendering the type sites page. Again as expected. BUT, clicking again to edit that site, e.g. on the same button and trying to save it, this time error is thrown that `id` is undefined in the backend. It looks like that `id` variable is not even in the method this time. This is my class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {toast} from 'react-toastify';

import {Content, Form, Items, Site, Header, Body, Info, Buttons, SitesList, SiteItem, Controls, Span} from './styles';

import Edit from './Edit';
import EditSite from './EditSite';
import NewType from './NewType';
import {SanctumContext} from "react-sanctum";

class Sites extends Component {

    static contextType = SanctumContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            siteId: null,
            edit: false,
            editSite: false,
            addSites: false,
            numberOfNewSites: null,
            new: false,
            sites: [],
            site: null,
            index: null,
            siteIndex: null
        }

        this.loadSites = this.loadSites.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.addSiteType = this.addSiteType.bind(this);
        this.addSites = this.addSites.bind(this);
        this.editSiteType = this.editSiteType.bind(this);
        this.editSite = this.editSite.bind(this);
        this.deleteSiteType = this.deleteSiteType.bind(this);
        this.deleteSite = this.deleteSite.bind(this);
    }

    async loadSites() {
        await axios.get("/api/v1/get-site-types/12").then(response => {
            this.setState({sites: response.data});
        })
    }

    addSiteType(data) {
        const sites = this.state.sites;

        sites.push(data);

        // call to add site on database

        this.setState({sites: sites, new: false});
    }

    addSites() {
        const Newsites = [];

        for (let i = 1; i <= this.state.numberOfNewSites; i++) {
            let site = {
                siteName: `New site ${i}`
            };

            Newsites.push(site);
        }

        axios.post("/api/v1/add-site", {
            site_id: this.state.siteId,
            sites: JSON.stringify(Newsites),
            count: this.state.numberOfNewSites
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.type === "success") {
                toast.success(response.data.message)
                const sites = this.state.sites;
                sites[this.state.index].sites = JSON.parse(response.data.sites);

                this.setState({
                    sites: sites,
                    addSites: null,
                    siteId: null
                });
            } else {
                toast.error(response.data.message)
            }
        })
        .catch(response => {
            toast.error("Some error occur. Please, try again.")
            this.setState({
                addSites: null,
                siteId: null
            });
        })
    }

    editSiteType(index, data) {
        const sites = this.state.sites;
        axios.post("/api/v1/edit-site-type", {
            id: this.state.site.id,
            title: data.title,
            price: data.price,
            rv: data.rv,
            pax: data.pax
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.type === "success") {
              toast.success(response.data.message)
                sites[index] = data;
                this.setState({sites: sites, edit: false});
            } else {
                toast.error(response.data.message)
            }
        })
        .catch(response => {
            toast.error("Some error occur. Please, try again.")
        })
    }

    editSite(typeIndex, itemIndex, data) {
        const sites = this.state.sites;

        sites[typeIndex].sites[itemIndex] = data;

        // call to edit site on database

        this.setState({sites: sites, editSite: false});
    }

    deleteSiteType(index) {
        const sites = this.state.sites;

        sites.splice(index, 1);

        // call to delete site type from database

        this.setState({sites: sites});
    }

    deleteSite(typeIndex, itemIndex) {
        const sites = this.state.sites;

        sites[typeIndex].sites.splice(itemIndex, 1);

        // call to delete site from database

        this.setState({sites: sites});
    }

    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (this.state.sites.length == 0) {
            toast.error('Please add at least one site type.');
            return;
        }

        this.props.nextStep(this.state);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadSites();
    }

    render() {
        let hasSites = this.state.sites.length > 0
        return(
            <Content>
                {!this.state.edit && !this.state.new && !this.state.editSite &&
                    <Form>
                        <button onClick={() => this.setState({new: true})}>New site type</button>
                        {hasSites ? (
                            <Items>
                                {this.state.sites.map((site, index) => (
                                    <Site>
                                        <Header>
                                            <h2>{site.title}</h2>
                                            <p>${site.price}</p>
                                        </Header>
                                        <Body>
                                            <Info>
                                                <p>{site.pax} Pax</p>
                                                <p>{site.rv} ft Max Length</p>
                                            </Info>
                                            {!this.state.addSites &&
                                            <Buttons>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.setState({site: site, index: index, addSites: true})}>Add sites</p>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.setState({site: site, index: index, edit: true})}>Edit</p>
                                                <p onClick={() => this.deleteSiteType(index)}>Delete</p>
                                            </Buttons>
                                            }

                                            {this.state.addSites && this.state.index == index &&
                                            <Buttons>
                                                <input type='number' min='1' max='5' onChange={(e) => this.setState({numberOfNewSites: e.target.value, siteId: site.id})} />
                                                <p onClick={() => this.addSites()}>Done</p>
                                            </Buttons>
                                            }
                                        </Body>
                                        {!this.state.addSites && site.sites.length > 0 &&
                                        <SitesList>
                                            {site.sites.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                                                <SiteItem>
                                                    <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                                                    <p onClick={() => this.setState({editSite: true, site: site, index: index, siteIndex: itemIndex})}>Edit</p>
                                                    <p onClick={() => this.deleteSite(index, itemIndex)}>Delete</p>
                                                </SiteItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </SitesList>
                                        }
                                    </Site>
                                ))}
                            </Items>
                        ) : ""}

                        <Controls>
                            <Span onClick={() => this.props.previous()}>Previous</Span>

                            <button onClick={(e) => this.submit(e)}>Proceed</button>
                        </Controls>
                    </Form>
                }

                {this.state.edit &&
                    <Edit
                        index={this.state.index}
                        site={this.state.site}
                        editSite={(index, data) => this.editSiteType(index, data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({edit: false})}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.editSite &&
                    <EditSite
                        index={this.state.index}
                        site={this.state.site}
                        siteIndex={this.state.siteIndex}
                        editSite={(typeIndex, siteIndex, data) => this.editSite(typeIndex, siteIndex, data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({editSite: false})}
                    />
                }

                {this.state.new &&
                    <NewType
                        addSiteType={(data) => this.addSiteType(data)}
                        goBack={() => this.setState({new: false})}
                    />
                }
            </Content>
        )
    }
}

export default Sites;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 <p onClick={() => this.setState({site: site, index: index, edit: true})}>Edit</p>
```

the "site" is an object and when you update that in this way, you should use somthing like this:

```html
function updateSiteEdit(site, newID, index) {

    this.setState(prevState => {
      let site = Object.assign({}, prevState.site);  // creating copy of state variable jasper
      site.id = newID;                     // update the name property, assign a new value                 
      return { site ,  index , edit: true};                                 // return new object jasper object
    })

}


///....

<p onClick={() => this.updateSiteEdit(site, sites.id, index)}>Edit</p>
```